# Como pegar o endereço através da Latitude e Longitude, formatado?

Tags: android

A partir de um clique no mapa, eu pego a latitude e longitude e o transformo em uma `String` de endereço, abaixo o código que utilizo:

```
private List<android.location.Address> addresses;

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

        if (mapclickActivate) {
            mappoint = latLng;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(activity, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mappoint.latitude, mappoint.longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mappoint != null) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("address", String.valueOf(addresses));
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(activity, PointInserirActivity.class);
                sendIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        }
}
```

Mas o endereço vem cheio de caracteres, conforme este exemplo:

> [Address[addressLines=[0:"Rua Martins, 132 - Vila Oeste",1:"Belo
>   Horizonte - MG",2:"Brasil"],feature=132,admin=Minas
>   Gerais,sub-admin=null,locality=Belo Horizonte,thoroughfare=Rua Pinto
>   Martins,postalCode=30532,countryCode=BR,countryName=Brasil,hasLatitude=true,latitude=-19.9398299,hasLongitude=true,longitude=-44.0038374,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]]

Como posso pegar somente o endereço *Rua número* - *bairro* - *país* .. por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questão resolvida da seguinte forma:

```
String street = null;
String city = null;
String adminArea = null; //estado
String country = null;
String address = null;

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(pontoMapeamento.latitude, pontoMapeamento.longitude, 1); 
        street = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);// rua numero e bairro
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();//cidade
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();//pais
        adminArea = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();//estado
        address = street + ", "+city+" - "+adminArea+" - "+country;//endereço da forma desejada
```

Answer (score 0):

O retorno das chamadas da API Geocoder inclui o endereço formatado (`results.formatted_address` do JSON), como pode ser visto na seguinte consulta:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-19.9398299,-44.0038374

A documentação da classe Address não apresenta o método getFormattedAddress(), assim uma alternativa é fazer a consulta "manualmente" (basta substituir o valor do parâmetro `latlng` na URL acima) e mapear o resultado da chamada em uma classe POJO.
Implementei essa funcionalidade em um projeto de teste que está disponível no meu GitHub. [Este link](https://github.com/MathiasBerwig/CloudVision/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/mathiasberwig/cloudvision/controller/service/RestApisConsumer.java#L217) mostra o método em que realizo a chamada.

Answer (score 0):

Só complementando a resposta do próprio Henrique Mendes, a variável "addresses" deve ser declarada como uma List de Address. Como demonstrado abaixo e explicado na [referência do Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocation(double,%2520double,%2520int)).

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(pontoMapeamento.latitude, pontoMapeamento.longitude, 1);
```